# WPF DatePicker Blackout date entered, prevent old value from being restored

Tags: wpf, datepicker, wpftoolkit

When I use the WPF 4.0 DatePicker with blackout date (or min/max), and the user enters a date that is blacked out by typing it in, the DatePicker reverts back to the original value.

This behavior is not the best for entering dates. If you key in the wrong year and tab out, it reverts back to the old value.

I'd like to be able to handle the error in code instead of just reverting back to the old value.

Comment: Can't you use the DateValidationError event on the DateTimePicker?

Comment: I have found a way using the DateValidationError event, but it's not optimal.